# New Contacts in Data Extension do not enter Marketing Cloud Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions

I'm trying to work out what I assume is something very obvious I'm missing in Journey Builder.

I've built an Automation which uses a Data Filter to filter from our main Contacts_DE (sync from Salesforce via Marketing Cloud Connector) to create a new Data Extension of the filtered Contacts (e.g. all Contacts with boolean field *X* = TRUE). The Automation then, via an SQL query, creates a sendable Data Extension which I can then select as a starting point for a Journey.

Contacts already in the sendable Data Extension get entered into the Journey and receive the relevant messages. Other Contacts, added after the Journey is activated, do not appear to enter the Journey, although do appear to be considered under the **Record Count** of the Journey. For example, in the below image, 2 Contacts existed in the Data Extension before the Journey was created and a further 1 Contact was added after the Journey was created. At 6am on 26 January, only the first 2 Contacts received the email.
[image]

The sendable Data Extension is updated correctly via the Automation Data Filter and SQL query. I could manually send an email to this Data Extension to all the Contacts, so I must be missing something *fairly obvious* when setting up the Journey.

**Thanks in advance!**

*I appreciate that there are some dates in the future from when this question was posted - this is a second version of the Journey with other dates, due to testing. The previous version of this Journey, with dates in the past, did not function at all and nothing was changed with this version.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for that is the schedule that has been set in your journey (can be seen right below the entry event's data extension section on the left hand side of your screenshot). In your case contact evailuation it is set to start on journey activation and to never repeat. Therefore only the contacts at activation time are considered and injected into the journey, but further entries will happen at a later stage.

In order for your automation run to trigger journey entries, you need to select the automation in your schedule configuration.

For scheduling the journey entries for a Data Extension entry source you have the following options:

- Run Once (on activation)
- Recurring (at a certain schedule you define)
- Automation (starts after every automation run)

When setting a recurring schedule, it is also important to define if all the records in the data extension should be injected into the journey or only the ones that have been added to your source data extension. Most of the time this depends on the way you select your audience and if you append or overwrite the data extension

**Related documentation:**

- [Schedule a Data Extension Entry Source](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_schedule_a_data_extension_entry_source.htm&type=5)
- [Choose How to Process Entry Source Data](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_manage_audience_data.htm&type=5)
- [Data Extension Entry Source](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_data_extension.htm&type=5)

Comment: Amazing - such a clear and helpful response. Thank you so much. I knew it would be something obvious I was overlooking!

Comment: @BenHollebon Great that my answer helped! Please mark the answer as accepted (checkmark icon on the left of it) so others can also see that this is the correct solution. Thank you!